# New rig z170, 15.04 - on board sound card not recognized

Tags: drivers, ati, 15.04, soundcard

I bought a new rig which consists of an I5 skylake CPU, Asus Z170 mobo, and a radeon 390 GPU.
Had some issues which by now are sorted, although I am left with the audio problem still, sound card is not being recognized.
Running Ubuntu 15.04 with the fglrx amd proprietary drivers.
See PS:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJAjS.png
Let me know which info is required from my side to help you help me.
This is the motherboard: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z170-PRO-GAMING/specifications/
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK, if anyone is having the same problem - the way I fixed it was installing the latest ALSA daily package from [here](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/+packages),  the [Vivid one](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/+files/oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms_0.201508262147~ubuntu15.04.1_all.deb).

Then I installed the .deb package using gdebi, rebooted &: issue resolved, that took a while to figure by myself since i am not too linux experienced, yet the simplest solution.

It did mess up my desktop experience somewhat, some icons in "settings" are gone, window background randomly missing etc, I fixed that by running:

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

Another thing that has gone missing is the actual sound  volume levels icon, to have it back I ran the following command via terminal, logged out and back in:

sudo apt-get install indicator-sound

So far so good

Comment: For Linux Mint 17.3 : I went more radical,  for some reason I had to go further - in addition to alsa package update I had to upgrade kernel from 3.19 to 4.3. So far no problems and the sound has appeared on the next restart.

Answer (score 1):

The sound issue was fixed by installing the drivers linked by Shay, however the missing background problem was still there even after reinstalling ubuntu-desktop.

I managed to fix the issue by reinstalling unity-control-center

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```