# Sound with Skylake on MSI H170M PRO-VDH

Tags: sound, msi

On a new machine based on MSI H170M PRO-VDH motherboard with a Intel Core i3 6100 processor, it's quite impossible to get sound. I try this page

[No audio output devices detected in new computer build with Skylake (Z170) motherboard in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672187/no-audio-output-devices-detected-in-new-computer-build-with-skylake-z170-mothe)

but nothing changes.

Any ideas to fix the problem?

Thanks