# No Audio from Ubuntu 14.04 installed Dell Optiplex 7040 PC

Tags: 14.04, sound, dell, pulseaudio, alsa

We have Dell Optiplex 7040 PC.
Everything works fine in factory installed Windows 7 OS.
However we installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it.
And now there is no audio from speakers as well as from headphones.

I have attached [Alas-info](https://github.com/AnkurTank/ubuntu_log/blob/master/alsa-info-log-optiplex-7040) for optiplex 7040.

Anyone has any suggestion/pointers ?

Below I pasted output of command `lspci | grep -i Audio`

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a170 (rev 31)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
```

Comment: Can you run this command from a terminal and post the output: lspci  | grep -i Audio

Comment: Added it in question.

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/672187/no-audio-output-devices-detected-in-new-computer-build-with-skylake-z170-mothe Why do you install Ubuntu 14.04 and not 16.04?

Comment: Thank you, I will try and update you on that. Everyone in our team is using Ubuntu 14.04 so i didn't want to take a diversion. Moreover I have also done build setup and also so don't want to disturb it.

Comment: Its not solving my issue :(

Comment: Which Answer did you follow?

Comment: I tried first and second answer. And after that I started following https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure but no luck so far :( Now I don't see any audio device. I see "Dummy output". I think i screwed it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Konrad suggested in comment section, this was because kernel in Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't have right audio driver(or doesn't have working audio driver).

I had posted question in the "Launchpad" forum and one of the suggestion was to update the kernel if I don't want to update to Ubuntu 16.04.

I used below command to update the kernel,

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-wily
```

Reference for above command was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431143/how-to-update-from-ubuntu-14-04-3-to-14-04-4) link.

Launchpad question link for your reference.
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+question/295963